Hi, I was developing a program & deployed it using solana playground, got into major issue
So issue is it showed it had to confirm 238 transactions, although it completed 237 successfully, it couldnt retry last tx and that didnt chain onchain and my SOL just never came back, how do I claim that back

To show program buffers use
solana program show --buffers

To close a buffer account and reclaim sol
solana program close --buffers <BADDRESS>

CLI docs
Similar-ish Answer
